# Reorder data in array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm posting data from a form with multiple fields. One form needs to send several rows to mySQL, ie.

```
Row1 -> Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4
Row2 -> Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4
etc...
```

I've created an array of arrays in the following format:

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
     [0] => Field1
     [1] => Field1 )
[1] => Array (
     [0] => Field2
     [1] => Field2 )
)
```

I can't figure out how to reorder them so I can loop through and insert them into my database. I need them to be

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
     [0] => Field1
     [1] => Field2 )
[1] => Array (
     [0] => Field1
     [1] => Field2 )
)
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: If you're posting data from your form, why are you not posting the data in the correct format right from the beginning?

Comment: The form has a variable number of rows, so there may be 1 set of fields posted or there may be 10 sets posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it's like flipping the matrix 90 degrees (sorry, don't know the proper term). I could not find any built-in function, so here it is -- this will work with ANY number of rows & columns (test data included).

```
<?php
// input data
$arr = array(
    array('field1-1', 'field1-2'),
    array('field2-1', 'field2-2'),
    array('field3-1', 'field3-2'),
    array('field4-1', 'field4-2'),
);

// some basic validations on input data
if (empty($arr) OR (!isset($arr[0])) OR (empty($arr[0])))
    die('empty or invalid source array');
// almost ready
$result = array();
$rowCount = count($arr[0]);
$fieldsCount = count($arr);
// go go go
for ($r = 0; $r < $rowCount; $r++)
{
    $row = array();
    for ($n = 0; $n < $fieldsCount; $n++)
    {
        $row[] = $arr[$n][$r];
    }
    $result[] = $row;
}

// results are in $result
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I've been working on this one for hours haha!!

Answer (score 0):

He's a possible solution for you. This one assume that both of the rows contain the exact same amount of key/value pairs and that each one is in the same order.

```
foreach ( $row1 as $key => $value )
  $data[$key] = array($row1[$key], $row2[$key]);
```

Where $row1 is the array contains all of the data that goes in the first row and $row2 is the array that contains all of the data for the second row.

Once the foreach is done, your data should be re-ordered properly in the $data array.